# How to get source package with aptitude on linux?

Tags: linux, package-managers

I can get source packages using apt-get source , but there a way to do this using aptitude ?
Also I downloaded the .deb package for python2.6 using aptitude and then unzipped it using ar.

```
aptitude download python2.6
ar xv python2.6_2.6.5-1ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

I also downloaded the python source using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get source python2.6
```

The contents of both the downloads are different. Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aptitude download python2.6` retrieves the binary package for `python2.6`.

`apt-get source python2.6` retrieves the **source** package that generates the binary package `python2.6`.

Source downloads will include the original source tarball, the debian diff and the signed certificate file.

Answer (score 3):

apt-get source *packagename*

apt-get source does not interact with the package system so mixing apt-get and aptitude is fine in this case.

You also do not have to be root to use apt-get source.

Answer (score 2):

The `.deb` package is the *binary* package, that is, the results of compiling the source package.  It is the thing that would be installed if you did `aptitude install <package>`.

It does not appear that aptitude can download source packages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may easily find them from ,Its removed from most of the places including ubuntu archives 
[Download Python 2.6_2.6XXX](http://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/armhf/python2.6/download)